# NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for main:Object running Calabash Android

Tags: android, calabash

I am trying to run calabash android using demo project. This is the first project I am trying to setup with calabash so really don't know if I have set it up properly. I am getting this error:

```
D:\AndroidDempProject>calabash-android run AndroidDemoProject.apk
No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreatin
g test server.
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for main:Object
(root) at -e:1
RuntimeError: Could not replace package name in manifest
calabash_build at D:/automation/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/c
alabash-android-0.4.14/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:37
chdir at org/jruby/RubyDir.java:465
calabash_build at D:/automation/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/c
alabash-android-0.4.14/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:32
mktmpdir at D:/automation/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/tmpdir.rb:97
calabash_build at D:/automation/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/c
alabash-android-0.4.14/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:31
build_test_server_if_needed at D:/automation/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/c
alabash-android-0.4.14/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:70
calabash_run at D:/automation/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/c
alabash-android-0.4.14/bin/calabash-android-run.rb:16
(root) at D:/automation/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/c
alabash-android-0.4.14/bin/calabash-android:71
load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046
(root) at D:\automation\jruby\bin\calabash-android:2
```

I have ruby 1.9.3p448 and calabash-android 0.4.14. I am running windows XP.

I have spent so many days trying to get it sorted. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to to update jRuby to 1.7.3 or later version.There was such [issue in jRuby](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-7048).